# Send IM with Subject through Lync SDK

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, lync, lync-2013

I have a code which sending Instant message to Lync Users by taking their Uri. But subject is not present for the conversation.

Answer (score 0):

This feature was removed in Lync 2013.

[See here...](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/3b4c851f-f510-4613-a750-9d3bad9bfe36/how-to-change-the-conversation-subject-in-lync-2013?forum=communicatorsdk)